# Editing vBulletin database has no effect on the site

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, vbulletin

This is a problem I've had forever with multiple vBulletin databases. I'm unable to edit the database to change settings such as the cookiepath, bburl or whether it's active or not. I mean, I can change them using PHPMyAdmin but the effects are no changes on the site.

Right now, I've lost access to an old installation and need to change the closed reason, bburl etc. I changed the text for the closed reason yet it still shows the text that it was before, the board is still closed and the bburl is still wrong.

I've verified that it is the right DB and the right server, as this has happened many times. Maybe I'm just missing something here? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

**vBulletin doesn't access the settings directly from the "settings" table.**

This info is for vBulletin 4.x, it may or may not be the same for other versions.

When settings are saved, they are serialized and stored in the "datastore" table. vBulletin pulls the data from the "datastore" table for active use.

---

I haven't had need to use the following steps, but I tested them by changing the protocol of the "bburl" entry in both the datastore and settings tables via PhpMyAdmin.

The particular settings you're looking for are all stored in the "options" array.

If you know the current data or variable names for the settings you want to change, you can search for them in the serialized string and replace them with the new settings.

The setting for an active board looks like this: `s:8:"bbactive";i:1;`
The reason looks like this:

```
s:14:"bbclosedreason";s:125:"<p>Sorry, the board is unavailable at the moment while we are testing some functionality.</p>
<p>We will be back soon...</p>";
```

---

Go to the "datastore" table and find the "options" entry in the "title" field.

Copy the serialized data from the "data" field associated with the "options" entry. Be sure to back it up in case your changes cause problems.

Search within the data for the items you want to change, when you change the data, make sure you use the correct serialized format by updating the length associated with that entry.

Update the "options" entry in the "datastore" table with the modified serialized data as well as updating the individual entries in the settings table.

---

The function that updates the "settings" and "datastore" tables is located here:
`includes\adminfunctions.php`

at approximately line number 2474 (depending on your version).

```
// #############################################################################
/**
* Reads settings from the settings then saves the values to the datastore
*
* After reading the contents of the setting table, the function will rebuild
* the $vbulletin->options array, then serialize the array and save that serialized
* array into the 'options' entry of the datastore in the database
*
* @return   array   The $vbulletin->options array
*/
function build_options()
{
    require_once(DIR . '/includes/adminfunctions_options.php');

    global $vbulletin;

    $vbulletin->options = array();

    $settings = $vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT varname, value, datatype FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "setting");
    while ($setting = $vbulletin->db->fetch_array($settings))
    {
        $vbulletin->options["$setting[varname]"] = validate_setting_value($setting['value'], $setting['datatype'], true, false);
    }

    if (substr($vbulletin->options['cookiepath'], -1, 1) != '/')
    {
        $vbulletin->options['cookiepath'] .= '/';
        $vbulletin->db->query_write("
            UPDATE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "setting
            SET value = '" . $vbulletin->db->escape_string($vbulletin->options['cookiepath']) . "'
            WHERE varname = 'cookiepath'
        ");
    }

    build_datastore('options', serialize($vbulletin->options), 1);

    return $vbulletin->options;
}
```